# How to convert bootstrap theme template to wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, templates, themes

The template i want to convert is:
http://www.dragdropsite.com/demo/mpurpose-free-multipurpose-twitter-bootstrap-3-template/

it has multiple stylesheets and wordpress doesnt recognise the theme when places in wp-content/themes/ folder

What are the steps involved to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it 'converting'. Wordpress themes are not just a simple html/css/js folder structure on the themes folder. Making a website work with wordpress is more involved than that. If you want to do it yourself you will need some experience with PHP. Wordpress's templating system is not very hard to learn but it won't happen on one sit.

I suggest you to take a look at this place so that a skilled person can do it for you

[Click here to check envato studio.](http://studio.envato.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bquery%5D=to%20wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same opinion with alejandrocavazos. While, it is not easy to create a wordpress theme, converting an existing bootstrap theme will be very difficult too.

But i have an idea. Find a similar wordpress theme. Save it with another name. Page by page edit the theme and copy/paste your theme's content into this wordpress theme. If you make the changes directly on a web server, you can see the changes realtime. I think this is the easiest way to do it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can do that**, but its quite difficult to convert entire HTML theme into wordpress directly. You need some basic understanding of wordpress and how it works.

There are some good articles available, please go through them. You will surely understand it well and will be able to convert your HTML into wordpress.

I assume here, you are using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) framework to design your static websites.

[1. How to Build a Responsive WordPress Theme with Bootstrap](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial)

[2. How to convert a Bootstrap site template into a WordPress website](https://www.charityandbiscuits.com/blog/tutorial-convert-bootstrap-site-template-wordpress/)

[3. Creating a WordPress Theme From Static HTML](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/creating-a-wordpress-theme-from-static-html--wp-34294)

Answer (score 0):

To Convert a Bootstrap 4 Template to a Wordpress Theme there is some work involved and there is no easier way to do in few clicks.

Start by using a starter theme such as Underscores.

-> Migrate your assets (js/css) from static template to the wordpress starter theme directory.

-> Start moving your page sections one by one (header, nav, page sections etc.)

-> To have more control from Wordpress dashboard, make use of plugins like Advanced Custom Fields, Custom Post Type UI and Contact Form 7.

For Detailed Tutorial you check out the Tutorial in this link

https://www.5balloons.info/convert-bootstrap-4-templates-wordpress-themes/